# SQL Join to Display Data from two Tables

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

There are two tables (Profile and Location) that have an ID field in common. Each table resides on a separate database on the same server. I need to display columns from each table. Profile table has 50 records that need to be displayed along with 50 matching records from Location table. Here is my query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.city, b.state FROM profile a JOIN Location b on a.id=b.id
```

When I run the above query more than 50 records are returned. When I remove b.state from the query, it returns 50 records. There is something not right when I add b.state to the query. The 50 states that need to be returned should be the states relevant to each city in the Profile table based on the common ID between the two.

Profile Table Data:

List item

Profile Table Data:
id|City
1|Chicag
2|Miami
3|Detroit

State Table Data:
id|State|Population
1|Illinois|10MM
2|Florida|20MM
3|Michigan|5MM
4|Virginia|7MM
5|Louisiana|3MM

I want to show everything that is in Profile table with what matches in State table based on the ID to show State and Population columns.

Comment: Please [edit] to include sample data from both tables as well as the results you'd like to obtain from that sample.

Comment: @sa-meeh In the below "answer" I am offering the result based on the data you provided in the question. But apparently you are looking for a different result. Could you please help us understand what you were expecting instead?

Comment: Hi @Ralph. I want to show a combination of fields from both tables. For instance, ID, City and State. If ID's on both tables match, the city and it's relevant state match based on the matching ID should be displayed. My query returns many results. I only have 50 records in Profile table. The query should only return those 50 records for which ID matches with the ID in State table.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but merely an easier to use format for the sample data:

```
declare @Profile table
    (
     id int identity(1, 1)
            primary key
            not null,
     City nvarchar(20)
    )

insert  into @Profile
values  (N'Chicago'),
        (N'Miami'),
        (N'Detroit')

declare @State table
    (
     id int identity(1, 1)
            primary key
            not null,
     State nvarchar(20),
     Population nvarchar(10)
    )

insert  into @State
values  (N'Illinois', N'10MM'),
        (N'Florida', N'20MM'),
        (N'Michigan', N'5MM'),
        (N'Virginia', N'7MM'),
        (N'Louisiana', N'3MM')

select  a.id,
        a.City,
        b.State
from    @Profile a
join    @State as b
on      a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an inner join to filter out non-matches (your example does not detail which type of join to use):

```
SELECT a.id, a.city, b.state 
FROM [profile] a 
INNER JOIN Location b on a.id=b.id
```

There also might be duplicates as well, which means you can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.city, b.state 
FROM [profile] a 
INNER JOIN Location b on a.id=b.id
```